# jmeter - how to make a groovy script easier to maintain for extentreports

Tags: jmeter

Below is a script that helps me build an extentreport for jmeter.  It is a JSR223 PostProcessor element.  It's working nicely however, the problem is that I have it duplicated after every HTTP Request in the script.  I have several scripts with 100's of HTTP requests that would need essentially a copy of the same PostProcessor groovy script.  This = hard to maintain!

I have tried splitting common parts into an external groovy script that I tried calling on the JSR223 PostProcessor.  I also tried chunking up the bits of the script and putting the values into a csv so that I could just update the csv values if anything changed.

I'm sure there's a cleaner/better way to do this but I'm still learning so I'm not sure of the best way to make this easier to maintain.  Here's the JSR223 PostProcessor.  The only bit that changes with each http request is the "//test result" section

```
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

//configure object for response data
def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();    

//configure extentreports objects
ExtentReports report;
ExtentTest testLogger;

//set location for file and report config
String resultsPath = "C:/portalQA/Automation/Results/";
String configPath = "C:/portalQA/Automation/JMeter/TestReportConfig/";
String reportPath = 
resultsPath+"Login_Results_${reportDate}_${currentTime}_${testenv}.html";

File file = new File(reportPath);

if (!file.exists()) {

    //if file does not exist, create it
    report = new ExtentReports(reportPath, true);
    report.loadConfig( new File(configPath+"extent-config.xml"));
} else {
    //else append to existing report
    report = new ExtentReports(reportPath, false);
    report.loadConfig( new File(configPath+"extent-config.xml"));
}

//test result

testLogger = report.startTest("Authenticate");
testLogger.assignCategory("Initialize Session");
if (response.contains("com.blah.portal.model.User")) {
    testLogger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Logged in with:  ${username}");
    testLogger.log(LogStatus.INFO, response);
} else {
    testLogger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Could not authenticate session");
    testLogger.log(LogStatus.INFO, response);
}

log.info("Authenticate");
print("Authenticate print");            

report.endTest(testLogger);
report.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

- I suggest using [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) instead. First of all, that way you will only have 1 listener in your script, which resolves your original problem, but it is a better option for writing into file in general, since listener has only one instance for all running threads, so you won't be creating a race condition when writing to file.
- If you rather have a post-processor, you can put it on higher level (not under any particular sampler) which will cause it to run after each request within the same scope or below.

  For example, configuration like

  ```
  Thread Group
      Post-processor
      Sampler 1
      ...
      Sampler N
  ```

  Will cause `Post-processor` to run after each `Sampler 1`...`Sampler N`

In both cases you may need to check which sampler you are processing, and skip those you don't want to add to your report (easiest way to do it, is to come up with some name convention for excluded samplers)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same challenge. In my case I need to check if JSON response from REST service was correct. I solved it in the following way.

[image]

I've created a **JSR223 PreProcessor** under the script root. It contains my custom class to handle JSON parsing and asserts.

```java
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult

class CustomAssert {

    def parseResponse(json) {
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        return jsonSlurper.parseText(json)
    }

    def assertResult(assertionResult, expectedResult, actualResult) {
        if (!expectedResult.equals(actualResult)) {
            assertionResult.setFailure(true);
            assertionResult.setFailureMessage("Expected ${expectedResult} but was ${actualResult}");
        }
    }
}

vars.putObject('customAssert', new CustomAssert())
```

Note the last line:

```java
vars.putObject('customAssert', new CustomAssert())
```

I put an instance of my `CustomAssert` to `vars`.

Then under my HTTP Requests I've added **JSR233 Assertion**

```java
def a = vars.getObject('customAssert')
def response = a.parseResponse(prev.getResponseDataAsString())

a.assertResult(AssertionResult, 'DRY', response.sensorResultHolderUIs[0].result.toString())
a.assertResult(AssertionResult, 'DRY', response.sensorResultHolderUIs[1].result.toString())
a.assertResult(AssertionResult, 'DRY', response.sensorResultHolderUIs[2].result.toString())
```

It basically retrieves the instance of `CustomAssert` from `vars` and calls its methods. I can put as many **JSR233 Assertion**s as I want. The only code that is copied is those two lines on top:

```java
def a = vars.getObject('customAssert')
def response = a.parseResponse(prev.getResponseDataAsString())
```

To sum up:

1. Take the common part of your code (that doesn't have to be copied).
2. Wrap it in a class.
3. Put the class in **JSR233 PreProcessor** under the root and export its instance via `vars`
4. Take the rest of your code and adjust it to use class defined in 2.
5. Put that code in as many **JSR233 Assertion**s as you want remembering to retrieve the instance created in 3. from `vars`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you user1053510.  Your advice lead me to build my own JSR223 Listener that renders the report.  Below is the code in my JSR223 Listener:

```
import com.aventstack.extentreports.*;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.*;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.*;

ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
ExtentReports extent;
ExtentTest test;

// create the HtmlReporter
htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("C:/AUTO_Results/Results_${testApp}_${reportDate}_${currentTime}_${testenv}.html");

//configure report
htmlReporter.config().setCreateOfflineReport(true);
htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(true);
htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("${testApp} Results");
htmlReporter.config().setEncoding("utf-8");
htmlReporter.config().setReportName("${testApp} Results ${reportDate}_${currentTime}_${testenv}");
htmlReporter.setAppendExisting(true);

// create ExtentReports
extent = new ExtentReports();

// attach reporter to ExtentReports
extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
extent.setReportUsesManualConfiguration(true); 

// Show Env section and set data on dashboard
extent.setSystemInfo("Tool","JMeter");
extent.setSystemInfo("Test Env","${testenv}");
extent.setSystemInfo("Test Date","${reportDate}");
extent.setSystemInfo("Test Time","${currentTime}");

//stringify test info
String threadName = sampler.getThreadName();
String samplerName = sampler.getName();
String requestData = props.get("propRequestData");
String respCode = props.get("propRespCode");
String respMessage = props.get("propRespMessage");
String responseData = props.get("propResponse");


// create test
test = extent.createTest(threadName+" - "+samplerName);
//test.assignCategory("API Testing");

// analyze sampler result
if (vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok") == "false") {
   log.error("FAILED: "+samplerName);
   print("FAILED: "+samplerName);
   test.fail(MarkupHelper.createLabel("FAILED:  "+sampler.getName(),ExtentColor.RED));

} else if (vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok") == "true") {
    if(responseData.contains("@error")) {
        log.info("FAILED: "+sampler.getName());
         print("FAILED: "+sampler.getName());
        test.fail(MarkupHelper.createLabel("FAILED:   "+sampler.getName(),ExtentColor.RED));

    } else if (responseData.contains("{")) {
            log.info("Passed: "+sampler.getName());
        print("Passed: "+sampler.getName());
            test.pass(MarkupHelper.createLabel("Passed:   "+sampler.getName(),ExtentColor.GREEN));
    }

} else {
    log.error("Something is really wonky");
    print("Something is really wonky");
    test.fatal("Something is really wonky");
}

//info messages
    test.info("RequestData:   "+requestData);
    test.info("Response Code and Message:    "+respCode+"   "+respMessage);
    test.info("ResponseData:    "+responseData);



//playing around
//markupify json into code blocks
//Markup m = MarkupHelper.createCodeBlock(requestData);
//test.info(MarkupHelper.createModal("Modal text"));
//Markup mCard = MarkupHelper.createCard(requestData, ExtentColor.CYAN);
//   test.info("Request  "+m);
//  test.info(mCard);
//     test.info("Response Data:     "+MarkupHelper.createCodeBlock(props.get("propResponse")));
//   test.info("ASSERTION MESSAGE:     "+props.get("propAssertion"));


// end the reporting and save the file
extent.flush();
```

Then in each threadgroup I have a BeanShell Assertion with these lines:

```
//request data
String requestData = new String(prev.SamplerData);
//String requestData = new String(requestData);
props.put("propRequestData", requestData);
//response data
String respData = new String(prev.ResponseData);
//String respData = new String(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
props.put("propResponse", respData);
//response code
String respCode = new String(prev.ResponseCode);
props.put("propRespCode",respCode);
//response message
String respMessage = new String(prev.ResponseMessage);
props.put("propRespMessage",respMessage);
```